# Two figures in one page of two columns style

Tags: floats

I want to insert two pictures in one page. Each picture should be expanded in two columns. So far the only thing that I can do is to insert one picture expanded in two columns but I can't put two pictures.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-10]

\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be okay of the figures are both at the `[t]`op rather than one at the `[t]`op and one placed `[h]`ere?

Comment: @Werner, thanks for the reply. I want to add two pictures with some lines between them.

Comment: What about one picture at the `[t]`op and one at the `[b]`ottom? That would have content between them.

Comment: On a side note, Section X.D of the documentation of the IEEEtran document class provides some background information on the use and limitations of double column floats.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for stating that. Actually, I was looking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `subfig` package is used because I assume you want two figures in one page as said in the title. For two-column style, you need `figure*` environment which explains why your second figure doesn't work properly.

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure*}[t]   % --- method 1, one figure environment. These can be arranged 
\centering           % horizonally (side by side) if ,say, 0.4\textwidth is used and \hfill is replaced by \quad instead.
\subfloat[figure 1]{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}}\hfill
\subfloat[figure 2]{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[t]   % -- method 2, two figure environments
\centering
\subfloat{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\subfloat{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

EDIT: The OP wants so add some text between the figures, thus `multicol` is recommnded to use in such case. Not `article` class with [twocolumn].

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\subfloat{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure*}

\begin{multicols}{2}
This is a sententence written between two figures.
This is a sententence written between two figures.
This is a sententence written between two figures.
This is a sententence written between two figures.
\end{multicols}


\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\subfloat{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much. How can I add lines between the two pictures while keeping them in one page?

Comment: In such case you need to use `muliticol` package with option for 2. so that you can insert \begin{multicols}{2} blah blah blah ...\end{multicols}. Note that the second figure should use [b] option. Don't use [twocolumn] as it is now.

Comment: @CroCo -- see my update.

Comment: I have a problem with your approach and including references. In my case, I'm using references (\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}). If I include two pictures the second one goes after the references list and the references list comes after the first picture. Any suggestions?

Comment: I got them to work by applying (\begin{figure*}[!t]) for each figure. I don't know why but they work.